# How to publish Facebook action in different formats?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I use my facebook app to publish user's activity on webapp to the user's activity log. currently my post publishes post in the below format!

[image: current format]

Wanted to know how to achieve different post format like the below

[image]

Comment: You have minimal control over which layout Facebook picks. It depends somewhat on the size/proportions of the image, I believe.

Comment: i have tried almost all and have searched the whole facebook docs, coudn't find an answer. Would be great if someone can answer.

Comment: As @ceejayoz said, I think it has to do with the size of the image. I assume you're using the facebook [metatags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags) and are providing the right image. If you're not, they suggest _you use an image of at least 1200x630 pixels._

Comment: @jalvarado91 tried that too. I'm expecting an answer not guess guys. Im desperate now :/ would be great if someone gives me that exact dimension.

Comment: Many things with Facebook are relegated to guesses and "this worked for me". Their algorithms are not publicly available and change rapidly and without warning. **Do not count on any solution working for long** - this layout has changed dozens of times already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It totally depends on Facebook, and it keeps changing. Nothing official published yet.